# In .NET MVC - how do we get back a parameter map of key/name values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to port this Spring MVC to .NET MVC. This Spring MVC can handle any submissions because I am a map:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/invokeFormStrSubmit.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ModelAndView addCustomer2(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

       java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]> formData =  request.getParameterMap();
```

This works nicely in Spring MVC.

[image]

How do we do this same in .NET MVC? I can read the parameters when I know the form fields.

Thank you for your help...

Comment: `request.getParameterMap();` similar to [`Request.Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.form?view=netframework-4.8) if my memory serves me right. and you can do something like `Request.Form["myFormField"]`.

Comment: Request.Form was the solution. My use case was to handle an unknown form - so i could not put in myFormField. I figured out how to loop through the form fields - i showed the logic below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request.Params is a NameValue collection of everything submitted in the form. See here:

[HttpRequest.Params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.params?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NameValueCollection -
a collection of associated String keys and String values that can be accessed either with the key or with the index.

```
 public System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Params { get; }
```

See below how to loop through the Params property for a page and how to display each key/value pair.

```
 string paramInfo = "";
 NameValueCollection pColl = Request.Params;
    for(int i = 0; i <= pColl.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        paramInfo += "Key: " + pColl.GetKey(i);
        string[] pValues = pColl.GetValues(i);
        for(int j = 0; j <= pValues.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            paramInfo += "Value:" + pValues[j];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTPRequest.Params is not defined for HTTPRequest that is part of **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http** namespace.

My objective was to build a COntroller that can handle form fields from an unknown form. It could be a JQuery Mobile Form with different fields. Since there are different fields - we cannot use a model.

I got this working with HTTPRequest.Form:

```
public IActionResult HandleSubmission()
        {
            //  NameValueCollection coll;
            try
            {
                var address = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
                var userAgent = Request.Headers["User-Agent"].FirstOrDefault();
                IFormCollection userdata = Request.Form;



                int myCount = userdata.Count;

                foreach (var item in userdata.Keys)
                {
                    String yy = "5";
                   String uu= item.ToString();

                    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues ttt; 

                    userdata.TryGetValue(uu, out ttt); 



                }

            }
            catch (Exception w)
            {
                Console.Write(w.StackTrace);
            }
```